# React Leaflet Fullscreen Control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, fullscreen

I'm using this library, but the fullscreenControl prop doesn't allow me to change the icon's position on the map. Any idea? remains fixed in the topleft.

im using this lib

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-fullscreen-control

Comment: i already found a way.
Just need to do this
<Map
      fullscreenControl={{ position: "bottomright" }}
>